When do two measured foliations on a surface define a Riemann surface structure?
Let $S$ be smooth surface of finite type, i.e. it has genus g and n punctures (assume $S$ to have negative Euler characteristic). We know by Hubbard-Masur theorem that given a measured foliation $(F,\mu)$ on $S$ and a Riemann surface structure $R$ there exits a unique holomorphic quadratic differential $q$ on that Riemann surface such that the vertical foliation induced by $q$ is measure equivalent to $(F,\mu)$. Moreover, we have the following homeomorphism
$$\mathcal{Q}(R) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$$
where $\mathcal{Q}(R)$ is the set of all holomorphic quadratic differentials on $R$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all measured foliations on $S$.
Suppose now we are given two measured foliations $(G,\lambda)$  and $(H,\delta)$ on $S$. What necessary and sufficient conditions should we impose on $(G,\lambda)$ and $(H,\delta)$ so that there exists a Riemann surface structure $R^{'}$ and quadratic differential $q^{'}$ on $R^{'}$ such that vertical and horizontal measured foliations induced by $q^{'}$ are measure equivalent to  $(G,\lambda)$ and $(H,\delta)$ respectively. Any help will be appreciated.

In the compact case, it is properly defined transversality.

Let $\tau$ and $\eta$ be measured laminations on a compact surface $S$. The existence of such a complex structure is equivalent to the measured foliations filling the surface in the sense that for any measured lamination $\nu$ we have $i(\tau, \nu) + i(\eta, \nu) > 0$, where $i(\cdot, \cdot)$ is intersection number. In this case, the point in Teichmüller space is unique.
The source here is Gardiner-Masur's paper "Extremal Length Geometry of Teichmüller space." The exact statement I mentioned above appears as Theorem 1.6 in Wentworth's paper "Energy of Harmonic Maps and Gardiner’s Formula," where a short harmonic-maps proof is given. The statement of Gardiner-Masur's theorem in their paper is in terms of slightly different terminology but is proved in the level of generality of surfaces with finitely many punctures. If one makes the standard modifications for punctures (e.g. poles of the quadratic differentials at punctures), I expect that unwinding their results should give an appropriate analogue in the case of punctures.

You can also deduce the punctured case from the closed case.  Namely, take a double cover (chosen to double the punctures) and then take another double cover that "unwinds" all punctures (so the number of punctures does not increase).  Now you can fill the punctures, apply the closed case, and push the answer down to the original, punctured, surface.
